# How to vectorize row iteration on pandas which involves conditioning on two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. I need to iterate on `df1` rows to get the timestamp and based on this timestamp `+- 1000 milliseconds` I filter data from `df2`. The below code snippet explains it clearly,

```
dataframes = []
for i in df1.index:
    tempdf = df1[df1.index.values == i]

    attributeName = tempdf['EventId'].iloc[0]
    timeStamp = tempdf['Timestamp'].iloc[0]
    fehlerStatus = tempdf['FehlerStatus'].iloc[0]
  
    tempdf2 = df2[(df2['DateTime']>=timeStamp + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=0)) & 
                        (df2['DateTime']<=timeStamp + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1000))].sort_values(by='DateTime', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    if not tempdf2.empty:
        tempdf2['TargetAttributePlusStatus'] = attributeName.replace(' ', '_') + fehlerStatus.replace(' ', '_')
        dataframes.append(tempdf2)

df = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=0)
```

The code above takes forever to get executed. Is there a more convenient way to vectorize this?

Comment: I don't see method to vectorize it - the only idea: for every value from `df1` runs filter on `df2` in separated `thread`, `process`, etc.

Comment: why not `for tempdf in df1.iterrows():`

Comment: `timedelta(milliseconds=0)` gives `0` so you could skip it. And `timedelta(milliseconds=1000)` you could create only once at start - maybe it will little reduce time.

Comment: @furas First, I did try with `df1.iterrows()` but no luck. The amount of time taken is the same.

Comment: @furas I did a test with the changes you mentioned above *with* and *without* `.iterrows()` 

```
i:3822     2m 22s (without `.iterrows()`)
i:3999     2m 22s (with `.iterrows()`)
```
Using `.iterrows()` does improve the performance but still the waiting time is long especially when there `df1` has `~100000` rows .

Comment: I would try to run it with `threads` or `multiprocessing`. OR with [dask](https://dask.org/) or [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/) which can run it with multiprocessing.

Comment: @furas I will give a shot with `dask` . However, could you provide an example using `thread` or `multiprocessing`?

Comment: simple examples you should have in documentation for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) and [threading](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading.html). But some methods may have one problem - they have to send data to new process and this can get time.

Comment: @furas From your above comment, what do you mean by "for every value from df1 runs filter on df2 in separated thread, process" ? I don't know how this will leverage the advantage of concurrency or parallelism. Because firstly there are ~100000 rows so do you mean I should spawn that many threads / processes? And again I need to wait for the thread to complete in order to get the result.